# **texstudio** identifies correct syntax as mistake

Tags: texstudio, syntax-highlighting, syntax-checker

In texstudio 4.5.1, I recently noticed it's highlighting all correct syntax as *latexSyntaxMistake* in an orange background.

Anyone know why this would be happening? Syntax checking is enabled in the **Editor** pane.

The file compiles with no errors.

Screenshot PNG attached.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you disable spell check?

Comment: Thanks, @rallg. I couldn't wait any longer. I reset all the settings files and it's no longer doing it. Spell check (ie. **Spelling** is checked under the _Editor_ settings in preferences and it's not highlighting acceptable code as mistaken.

Comment: If you want anyone to test your problem, you should provide a copiable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).